# Performing checks on Liquibase scripts

Tags: java, oracle, continuous-integration, liquibase

I regularly face issues when deploying my Liquibase scripts on Oracle, because I don't have an easy way to run them before I deploy them. They always run fine on a fresh H2 DB, but when I deploy in the pipeline, I often face basic issues.

I would like to implement some quality checks on my scripts **before** they are deployed, typically as part of the build. Is there an easy way to do that ? For example, something basic like checking that column and table names are not too long for Oracle.. Because I don't do it very often, I tend to forget about that limit, and when I deploy on Oracle, I get a bad surprise..

Thanks !

Comment: It wouldn't be that easy but I suggest to keep release data in some database. We used docker for this. So If you have docker with prvious schema, you can create tag and then everytime revert to it or move to another tag

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to parse the latest Liquibase files I create, and perform some basic checks. I guess this can be extended for more advanced checks, but that's already quite nice. Here are 4 tests, using AssertJ for assertions

```
import liquibase.change.core.AddColumnChange;
import liquibase.change.core.CreateTableChange;
import liquibase.change.core.RenameColumnChange;
import liquibase.change.core.RenameTableChange;
import liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogParameters;
import liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet;
import liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog;
import liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException;
import liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser;
import liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class LiquibaseScriptsTest {

    public static final String LIQUIBASE_FILES_LOCATION = "src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/*.yml";

    public static final int NB_LAST_FILES_TO_CHECK = 5;

    private static final int ORACLE_TABLE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 30;

    private static final int ORACLE_COLUMN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 30;

    private List<DatabaseChangeLog> scriptsToCheck;

    private final static Comparator<Resource> resourceComparator = (r1, r2) -> r1.getFilename().compareTo(r2.getFilename());

    private static YamlChangeLogParser parser = new YamlChangeLogParser();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {

        ResourcePatternResolver resourceFinder = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        Resource[] resources = resourceFinder.getResources("file:" + LIQUIBASE_FILES_LOCATION);

        scriptsToCheck = Arrays.asList(resources).stream()
                //looking only at the latest files, assuming their name is indexed
                .sorted(resourceComparator.reversed())
                .limit(NB_LAST_FILES_TO_CHECK)
                .map(r -> toLiquibaseScript(r))
                .collect(toList());
    }

    @Test
    public void someScriptsAreChecked() {
        assertThat(scriptsToCheck).as("There's no script to check - are you sure you configured the path correctly ? ").isNotEmpty();
        assertThat(scriptsToCheck.size()).isLessThanOrEqualTo(NB_LAST_FILES_TO_CHECK);
    }

    @Test
    public void tableNamesShouldBeLessThanOracleMaxSize_whenCreated() {

        Stream<CreateTableChange> createTableChanges = getChangesAsStreamOf(CreateTableChange.class);

        createTableChanges.forEach(tableCreationChange -> {

            assertThat(tableCreationChange.getTableName().length())
                    .as("change " + tableCreationChange.getChangeSet().getId() + " - table name is too long - " +
                            tableCreationChange.getTableName() + " is " + tableCreationChange.getTableName().length() +
                            "char long while maximum for Oracle is " + ORACLE_TABLE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
                    .isLessThanOrEqualTo(ORACLE_TABLE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void tableNamesShouldBeLessThanOracleMaxSize_whenModified() {

        Stream<RenameTableChange> renameTableChanges = getChangesAsStreamOf(RenameTableChange.class);

        renameTableChanges.forEach(tableRenameChange -> {

            assertThat(tableRenameChange.getNewTableName().length())
                    .as("change " + tableRenameChange.getChangeSet().getId() + " - table name is too long - " +
                            tableRenameChange.getNewTableName() + " is " + tableRenameChange.getNewTableName().length() +
                            "char long while maximum for Oracle is " + ORACLE_TABLE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
                    .isLessThanOrEqualTo(ORACLE_TABLE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void columnNamesShouldBeLessThanOracleMaxSize_whenCreated() {

        Stream<AddColumnChange> addColumnChanges = getChangesAsStreamOf(AddColumnChange.class);

        addColumnChanges.flatMap(columnCreationChanges -> columnCreationChanges.getColumns().stream())
                        .forEach(columnCreationChange -> {

                    assertThat(columnCreationChange.getName().length())
                            .as("column name is too long - " + columnCreationChange.getName() + " is " + columnCreationChange.getName().length() +
                                    "char long while maximum for Oracle is " + ORACLE_COLUMN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
                            .isLessThanOrEqualTo(ORACLE_COLUMN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);

                });
    }

    @Test
    public void columnNamesShouldBeLessThanOracleMaxSize_whenModified() {

        Stream<RenameColumnChange> renameColumnChanges = getChangesAsStreamOf(RenameColumnChange.class);

        renameColumnChanges.forEach(columnRenameChange -> {

                    assertThat(columnRenameChange.getNewColumnName().length())
                            .as("column name is too long - " + columnRenameChange.getNewColumnName() + " is " +
                                    columnRenameChange.getNewColumnName().length() + "char long while maximum for Oracle is " +
                                    ORACLE_COLUMN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
                            .isLessThanOrEqualTo(ORACLE_COLUMN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);

                });
    }

    private <E> Stream<E> getChangesAsStreamOf(Class E) {
        Stream<Stream<ChangeSet>> changeSets = scriptsToCheck.stream().map(script -> script.getChangeSets().stream());

        Stream<ChangeSet> changeSetStream = changeSets.flatMap(changeSet -> changeSet);

        return changeSetStream.flatMap(changeSet -> changeSet.getChanges().stream())
                .filter(E::isInstance)
                .map(change -> (E) change);
    }

    private DatabaseChangeLog toLiquibaseScript(Resource r) {
        try {

            System.out.println("going to apply checks on "+r.getFilename());

            return parser.parse(r.getFile().getCanonicalPath(), new ChangeLogParameters(), new FileSystemResourceAccessor());
        } catch (ChangeLogParseException | IOException e) {
            fail("couldn't parse Liquibase script - " + r.getFilename() + " - " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you check the validity of column types?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following batch in order to rollback the database state to date/time right before if any issue happen during update process.
of corse you can run this batch using maven during test scope

```
@ECHO OFF
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2%T%ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,2%
java -jar path/to/liquibase.jar update
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO ProcessError
:ProcessError
ECHO error while executing liquibase scripts
ECHO Rolling back to state at %ldt%
java -jar path/to/liquibase.jar rollbackToDateSQL %ldt%
```

i am using liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar & ojdbc5-11.1.0.7.0.jar with the following liquibase.properties file.

```
#liquibase.properties
driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
classpath: path/to/ojdbc.jar
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@****:port:SID
username: OWNER
password: ****
changeLogFile:databaseChangeLog.xml
logLevel: debug
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be ready to start looking at a commercial solution like [Datical DB](http://www.datical.com/) that uses Liquibase internally, but adds things like forecasting, which simulates applying the changes to an abstract in-memory database model. We also have a rules engine that can do very complex checks of your database and your changelog. Full disclosure - I am an employee of Datical.